# uninitialized constant SampleController::Delayed while executing delayed_job worker method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am getting the following error while executing SampleController.

```
uninitialized constant IdeasController::Delayed
```

I have already started the delayed_job by using rake jobs:work. I have the following delayed_job code in SampleController.rb

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedWorker.new({:model=>object.class.to_s,:object_id=>object.id,:meth=>:create_suggestion}))
```

delayed_worker.rb contains the following code:

```
class DelayedWorker < Struct.new(:options)

  def perform

    if obj=Object.const_get(options[:model]).find(options[:object_id])

      if (options[:para] ? obj.send(options[:meth],options[:para].first) : obj.send(options[:meth]))
        puts "Successfull"
      else
        puts "Failed"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any one please help me for resolving this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedWorker.new({:model=>object.class.to_s,:object_id=>object.id,:meth=>:create_suggestion}))
```

to

```
::Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedWorker.new({:model=>object.class.to_s,:object_id=>object.id,:meth=>:create_suggestion}))
```

Comment: I have tried with this, but this time we are getting the following error
uninitialized constant Delayed

Comment: @SravanKumar you are sure you have delayed_job gem properly installed?

Comment: Yes, I have also ran db:migrate rake task.jobs:work rake task is also working fine.